# How to translate button in menu depending on the language of the site - use JS or PHP

Tags: javascript, php

https://jsfiddle.net/09fqps3n/

```
<div class="nav-button">
        <a href="#" class="button">
          <svg 
           ...
          </svg>
          <span>Contact Us</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

I have WPML translator plugin, it add to domain /language in link (for example domain.com/en, domain.com/ru and so on). I created the menu on the top of my site and it translates my ul-li list.

So

I want to translate the button "Contact Us". What is the simpliest way how can i do it use JS or PHP. I imagine it something like this: when i have /ru - my button become to be "Связаться с нами"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wpml plugin has options to change translation for individual strings. Assuming your code has

```
<span>Contact Us</span>
```

It should have been output using php like this

```
<span><?php echo __('Contact Us', 'text-domain')__; ?></span>
```

(More about `text-domain` later)

Then you can go to wpml menu in admin and choose "Theme and Plugin Localization" where you will see possibility to translate all plugins and themes in their different text-domains.

As for your theme, it should appear there with its text-domain name. Then you can "Scan selected themes for strings" and afterwards once you click on your theme name you will see all the strings that were found. Now translate.